# File Upload Limited to 6 request on Chrome

Tags: java, php, http, file-upload, plupload

I know that Google Chrome limited to 6 http request.

That's why on my simple file uploader, I can only upload 6 file at the same time. and if I firebug it, it will show 6 http Post request working.

My question is, why upload software such as java uploader or plupload is not limited? (when I firebug it, it does not show the http request).

What did they do? Did they use other method aside from POST request to upload file?

Answer (score 1):

I think that you should ask opposite question: why Chrome is limited? BTW at least in past MSIE was limited by 2 simultaneous uploads that was configured via registtry.

Browsers limit number of uploads to be more stable. Otherwise not responsible developers can cause browser to crash. Lower level tools that are developed for engineers rather than end users do not limit this number transferring this responsibility to application developer.

Comment: Yes, I know that all browser not just Chrome limit simultaneous upload differently. Chrome : 6, Firefox also 6 or 4 I believe. but my question is what if.. some 'crazy people' open up different file sharing site, such as megaupload, plupload, etc2 up until 7 site. and try to upload different file which is large enough that none of them finished upload yet. that means, the last site will seems like it's not working, because 6 request has been made on the other site. I hope you understand what I meant.

Comment: @Harts Did you try it with different servers? The limit might be only over a single connection.

Comment: @Harts I don't think the limit is on "all servers". It should be a limit per server, i.e. max 6 connections per server. Browsers do that to be "nice" to not to overload servers. But anyone can write a program that attempts to open 1000 connections to a server. Hopefully the server have defense measure for that.